# Populate a combobox in Angular with Java BackEnd

Tags: angularjs, ajax

The thing is as told in the title.

```css
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('sbi', [ ]);
    app.controller('PanelController', function (){
        this.tab = 1;

        this.selectTab = function (setTab){
            this.tab = setTab;
        };
        this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
            return this.tab === checkTab;
        };
      });


app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
      'use strict';

      $scope.data = { "name": ""};

        $scope.reset = function() {
          $scope.data.name = "";
          $scope.data.codeSub = "";
          $scope.data.cognSub = "";
          $scope.data.codfis = "";
          $scope.data.drpdownvalue = "";
          $scope.form.$setPristine();
        }
    });
```

```
app.controller('DdController', function($scope, $compile) {
    'use strict';

    var loadUrl = contextName+"/subinstaller/inserimento/dettaglio.do?methodName=doListenerStato";
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url : loadUrl,
        type: "GET",
        data: data, 
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        complete: function(){
            _show_(false,'waitPanel');
        },
        success : function (data, stato) {
            $('#service').empty()
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $("#service").append($('<option value="'+data[i].code+'">'+data[i].descr+'</option>'));                 
            }
            $('#service').trigger("chosen:updated");
        },
        error : function (richiesta, stato, errori) {
            _show_(false,'waitPanel');
            alert("error caricaServices");
        }
    });
    });


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script><!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sbi">
<head>
    <link href="utils/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <style>
        table, td  { border-width: 2px; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 15px; color: #000000; text-align: center; }
        table.pos_fixed1 { position:relative; top:30px; left:10px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<form name="form">
            <div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <table summary="" width="10%" class="pos_fixed1" align="center">
            <tr><td>Code Subinstaller<br><input type="text" ng-model="data.codeSub" /></td>
            <td>Stato<br>
            <select ng-model="data.drpdownvalue">
            <option value=""> -- Seleziona -- </option>
        </select> </td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Nome Sub Installer<input type="text" ng-model="data.name" /></td>
            <td>Cognome Sub Installer<input type="text" ng-model="data.cognSub" /></td>
            <td>Codice Fiscale<input type="text" ng-model="data.codfis" /></td></tr>
        </table><br><br>
        </form>
        <section>
            <div class="text-center">
            <form name="form" id="form" novalidate>
                  <div>
            <button class="btn-xs" data-ng-click="">Cerca</button>
            <button class="btn-xs" ng-click="reset()">Pulisci</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </section>


 <section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills" >
<li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(1) }"> <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Risultati</a></li>
<li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(2) }"> <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Dettaglio</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
 <h4>Risultati</h4>
 <p> :))) </p>
 </div>
  <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
 <h4>Dettaglio</h4>
 <p> Not skilled enough yet</p>
 </div>




</section>



<script type="text/javascript" src="utils/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/sbi_inserimento_controller1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The function "DoListenerStato" has its query and it works (tried in Java)
But the combobox is not being populated.
Have I used ajax correctly? If so, what can I do?
I'd prefer to keep using ajax for this work, if possible.

Comment: `$.ajax` is `jQuery`. Why do you wanna mix and use when you can use `Angular`'s own ajax `$http`?

Comment: It's a work thing, I don't make the rules.

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. **Use the [$http Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)** which is integrated with the AngularJS execution context.

Comment: In AngularJS a combobox is populated using either the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) or [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directives. For more information, see [AngularJS `select` directive API Reference (Matching model and option values)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#matching-model-and-option-values).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `$http.get` instead of `$.ajax`.

in `Controller.js` file:

```
$scope.data = {};
$http.get(loadUrl).then(function (response){
     $scope.data = response.data;
     //success callback
}, function (response) {
    //error callback
});
```

Since you already have `data.****` in your `ng-model` this should solve it.

Comment: In AngularJS a combobox is populated using either the [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) or [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directives. For more information, see [AngularJS `select` directive API Reference (Matching model and option values)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#matching-model-and-option-values).